# update or refresh gridview in asp.net when there is any Insert,Update or Delete in the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, gridview

I have a gridview in my aspx page and when a database table record is modified I like to refresh the grid automatically. Can I do any kind of trigger between database table and aspx page by which it will automatically fire any event and do the grid refresh?

Remember I can not refresh the page after certain time interval. As per the requirement I can not refresh the grid using the ajax too after a certain interval. Only I can refresh the grid whenever the record of a table will be modified. I need to follow the mechanism of facebook as there is any change by any user, the record will automatically be viable to all the logged in users.

Can anyone suggest how can I do it ?

Comment: What version of SQL do you have, this is possible in the 2012 version of SQL. If you have something like 2008 RT I think you need to script.

Comment: I have sql server 2008 R2. What I need to do ??

Comment: how you enter data in your gridview using button or link.

Comment: Data can be enter by any other logged user other than me and it is by a button. I just need to fire any event from the database if there is any changes in the table I need to refresh all the grids of all the logged in users automatically without refreshing the page. Also remember I can not refresh the grid after few time by the refresh mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

you can user SignalR for building a real time application.

have a look at this link it have exactly what you want

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr

Answer (score 0):

You can use update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTamplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" >

    --------
    </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this will help you.